# How do you say "I quickly forgot..." (As in an emotion you were feeling)

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to figure out how I could express that I had a feeling/emotion. and then, after a certain event happend/began I "Quickly forgot" that I had that emotion.
In english we could say "At the beginning of the date I was really hungry, but after talking with her for a couple of minutes I quickly forgot my hunger" 
Could I say 
"我就快忘了我以前饿的样子。 "

Comment: Chinese would probably just say: 我就不饿了.

Comment: 我们一见面就聊的特别开心，我*都忘了*我还饿着肚子呢。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you forgot your hunger because of work or study, you can say 废寝忘食, which means you work/study too hard to eat/sleep.
PS: You can not say 废寝忘食 for a girl.

for this sentence "At the beginning of the date I was really hungry, but after talking with her for a couple of minutes I quickly forgot my hunger", you can say:
我刚见到她的时候还饿得很，但和她聊了几分钟之后很快就被我抛到脑后了。

Answer (score 0):

There is an exact word in Chinese for this, that is "淡忘"。